# Bind and pass around templated function calls

Tags: c++, templates, stdbind

This doesn't work:
http://ideone.com/mUL5Y

Figured I helped it a little with deducting that type:
http://ideone.com/mGfUj

Doesn't work either! I don't understand why not.

How should I do this?

Comment: You couldn't just copy the code into the post? You're making us look at an off-site source for a 24-line piece of code?

Comment: @NicolBolas Yes. You get the errors, can clone it, player around with it a bit... it's considered proper netiquette on irc://chat.freenode.net/##c++ and I figured it was convenient here too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to be that `std::bind` is internally passing the *evaluated results* of the `Callable` (it's actually a `std::bind<>` type) object `c` when you pass it for a second time here:

```
part2(std::bind(&Quux::part3<Callable>, this, 3, c))
```

It's not passing an un-evaluated version of the `std::bind` object like you're assuming.

Therefore since your `f` function returns a `void` type, the result of the `c` expression is internally passed as a `void` type, and not an un-evaluated callable function object.  Thus when you attempt to call the `Callable` object `c` in `Quux::part2`, which in-turn attempts to evaluate the call `c` in `Quux::part3`, it cannot pass a callable object as the second argument to `Quux::part3`, since the type it is passing is actually a `void` type, and not a callable type.

For further reference, see here: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind

Note particularly that:

> If `std::is_bind_expression<T>::value==true` (i.e., another `std::bind()` subexpression was used as an argument in the initial call to `bind`), then that bind-subexpression is invoked immediately and its **result** is passed to the function.

If you want to delay the evaluation so that it happens when you want it to, and not when you pass a `std::bind` sub-expression, you will have to look for another method, such as a lambda, or `std::function<>` object, a functor, or some other class object type that is both callable and can store a state which can be evaluated later.

Comment: How can it be evaluated? c isn't called anywhere... why does it turn from void() to void?

Comment: When you pass a `std::bind` to another `std::bind`, the first sub-expression is evaluated, and the *results* are passed to the second `std::bind` ... so if you evaluate a `void (*)(int)`, you're going to end up with a `void` type as the result, not a callable `void(*)(int)`.  Although you are not explicitly calling `c`, it is in fact being called behind the scenes because of the nested `std::bind` expressions, with the result of the call being passed on, not the callable object itself.

Comment: BTW, I think you'll get a better idea of where and how this transformation takes place if you use normal free-standing functions rather than class methods.  [Here is an example with the associated error messages](http://ideone.com/CCQot)

Comment: Question remains: Why? This doesn't seem to make a lot of sense to me.